# How to specify the amount of data under the graph in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I specify how much data of the total is under the arrow?

Source:

```
data_arc['Активная мощность'].hist(bins=100, figsize=(10,6), label='Активная мощность')
pop = data_arc['Активная мощность']
plt.title('График столбца "Активная мощность"')
plt.xlabel('Значение показателя')
plt.ylabel('Количество значений')

index1 = 2
index2 = 4
h = max(data_arc['Активная мощность'][index1:index2]) # maximum of the involved bar heights
bx = [index1, index1, index2-0.27, index2-0.27]
by = [h + 0.5, h + 50, h + 50, h + 0.5]
plt.plot(bx, by, 'k-', lw=2)
plt.text((index1 + index2) / 2, h + 55, f'{sum(pop[index1:index2]):.0f}% данных', size=10, ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.legend()
plt.show();
```

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate how much of the data is >= 2.0, or how to set the limits on the graph so some of that data is out of frame?

Comment: how to calculate how much of the data is >= 2.0